# Query for null and non null at the same time

Tags: mysql, sql, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I've got this entity:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@ToString
@Accessors(chain = true)
@Entity
@Table(name = "offer_categs")
public class OfferCateg {

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   private Long id;

   private String name;

   @Nullable
   private String image;

   @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id")
   private OfferCateg parent;

   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent",
           cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE,
           fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
           orphanRemoval = true)
   private Set<OfferCateg> children; 

}
```

I'm trying to just create categories and subcategories. My problem is that when using the below method, parent_id might be null in case of a root category. How can I make the query to allow for that? I can't use IS NULL. Should I make two queries and be careful of the calling parent_id value ?

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM offer_categs oc WHERE oc.parent_id = ?1 AND oc.name = ?2", nativeQuery = true)
OfferCateg findByNameAndParent(@Nullable Long parentId, String name);
```

**EDIT**

I changed the query to this and it seems to be working

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM offer_categs oc WHERE " +
        "(oc.parent_id = ?1 AND oc.name = ?2) OR" +
        "(oc.parent_id IS NULL AND ?1 IS NULL AND oc.name = ?2)",
        nativeQuery = true)
OfferCateg findByNameAndParent(@Nullable Long parentId, String name);
```

BUT...isn't this overkill ?! I'm sure it can be done more easily.

Comment: It's not an overkill (you can pull the `oc.name = ?2` part out of both expressions in brackets, but your RDBMS query analyzer probably doesn't care either way).

Comment: hmm, i don't think I can. the combined parent_id and name makes the item unique ...

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, but in any case, what I meant is that `(A AND C) OR (B AND C)` is the same as `C AND (A OR B)`

Comment: I guess you can write that as the answer so I can accept it. It's better than nothing i guess. Thanks !